# Can't configure GPU bios properly

Tags: gpu, ethereum, mining

I have 6 GPUs of RX470. It should be mining average 25-27 mh/s each but it's only 20 mh/s. Overall is 120 instead of 150-170. I think the problem is GPU bios configuration but can't figure out any other thing. Any  suggestions?

Comment: What operating system and drivers are you using?

Comment: This seems like a hardware/software configuration question, rather than a programming question. Voting to close.

Answer (score 0):

25 mh/s is what you would expect from an RX 480 stock. To get the same hashrate for RX 470, you'd be looking at overclocking memory speed (+600). In terms of how to overclock, it depends on whether your running linux or windows.